# find and replace in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets in the one spreadsheet 'Stats' and 'People' (this is a complete list of every person with their id number). I am trying to add the person's number into 'Col A' from a matching record in the 'persons' sheet.

Below is the snippet of the two sheets.

```
    'Stats' tab
    Col A = (needing the person ID number here from the 'Col B' in the 'persons' sheet)
    Col J = Persons Name

    'Persons' tab
    Col A = Persons Name
    Col B = Persons ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer if you in the forth row

=VLOOKUP(J4,people!A:B,2,FALSE)

'J4' = is the ColJ with the person name
'J4,people!A:B' = is the range to search
'2' = is the second col to display
'false' = honesty no idea it works.

Comment: The last argument, FALSE, is whether search is approximate or not. If TRUE, VLOOKUP will return an inexact match (based on alphabetical sorting) even if the exact value is not there. If FALSE, it will always look for an exact match or return error. Read the manual for VLOOKUP for more info

Answer (score 1):

QUERY could be used here. Try:

```
=QUERY(Persons!A2:ZZ, "SELECT B WHERE A = J)
```